# Laravel download files with two tables in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-storage

I hope so im getting close to final stage. I uploading file to `storage/files/` and create uniq folder for each upload file with `id_message` without problem and store file data in table `files`

Final path of file is `/storage/files/{id_message}/{file_name}` both variables `id_message` and `file_name` are in table `files`.

`FileController` function for `fileUpload`:

```
    function fileUpload(Request $request)
    {
    $request->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    
    $idParameter = $request->id_message=$request->id_message;

    $result=$request->file('file_path')->store('files/'.$idParameter);

    $file = new File;
    $file->id_message=$idParameter;
    $file->file_path=$result;
    $file->file_name=$request->file('file_path')->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->save();
```

after upload i have this data in table `files`:

```
id    id_message    file_name
1     000001        Myfile.zip
```

`/storage/app/files/000001/Myfile.zip`

`FileController` : `getDownload`

```
   public function getDownload($id)
   {
      $resultFile = DB::table('files')->where('id_message',$id)->first();

      $attachment = store_path().'/' . $resultFile->id_message . '/' . $resultFile->file_name;

      return response()->download($attachment);
   }
```

`route`

```
Route::get('download/{id}/{fileName}', 'FileController@getDownload')->name('downloadFile');
```

`view.blade`

```
   <td><a href="{{ route ('downloadFile', $resultFile->file_name)}}">Download</a></td>
```

`error`

```
Undefined variable:resultFile
```

do i getting closer to finaly download file in laravel ?

`controller for view` table `users`

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    request()->validate([
        'id_message' => 'required',
        'sms_code' => 'required',
    ]);
    
    $credentials = $request->only('id_message', 'sms_code');
    $request->session()->flash('success','');
                
    if ($user=User::where($credentials)->first()) {
        auth()->login($user);
    
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard')->with('success','');
        }
        
    return Redirect::to("login")->with(['url_attribute' => $url_attribute,'id_message' => $id_message])->with('error','');
    }

public function dashboard()
{
  if(Auth::check())
  {
    return view('dashboard');
  }
   return Redirect::to("login")->withSuccess('Opps! You do not have access');
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the controller for that  view ?

Comment: @KhalidKhan controller added to question

Comment: the controller which is returning the view which have that downloading link,  Must have  $resultFile = DB::table('files')->where('id_message',$id)->first(); this as compact in the return statement in order to access that variable. I hope you get my point]

Comment: @Khalid Khan do you know where to place ?

Comment: yes bro, tell me your view name and controller function method name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading zeros may be getting stripped if its converted to integer.

Try adding padding to `$id` once it's passed to `getDownload`:

```
str_pad($id, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: ````000001```` was example, actualy working with ````802815```` and etc

Comment: Does the error occur showing the route address on the blade view? or if you access the download route directly?